# wordpress : How to specify the cause "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: php, wordpress, lets-encrypt, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have used Let's Encrypt for WordPress on AWS Lightsail.

I found that it was expired because I didn't renew it.

So I tried the Let's encrypt to renew, the bitnami guide https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/ and Cloudflare https://www.cloudflare.com/ to apply SSL.

But my site is not displayed after trying various things.

When I try to access my site in chrome, the following message is displayed.

```
This site can’t be reached
mydomain.com refused to connect.

Try:
- Checking the connection
- Checking the proxy and the firewall

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSE
```

I tried `https://`, `https://www`, `http://` and `http://www`, but the same error message was displayed in chrome.

Similar message is displayed in Internet Explorer when I access my site.

When I tried to access with public IP, such as 54.249.xxx.xxx, the result is the same. (This site can’t be reached)

I also checked /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs.

There are some such as `error_log-20180dd.gz` files in /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs.

But I don't know which message is useful to solve the problem.

What should I check at the beginning? Which log should I check?

It would be appreciated if you could give me some hint.

Comment: I don't think this is because of server configuration as it would've been 50X error if it was a server related issue. Although you can check your error-log file if you can find anything.there. You can try connecting to your hosting provider they might know the cause.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. First of all, did you check if all the services of the Bitnami installation are up and running? `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status`. If they are not, please start them `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start`. In case Apache returns an error message, could you please share it with us? I think that Apache is not working because there is any configuration issue that prevents it to start. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you first enable the WordPress debug to output errors?

Open wp-config.php and change this:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

To this:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug

What errors does that display for you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @David.J. I tried `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`, `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` and `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);`. But nothing happened. It would be appreciated where I should check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @David.J. I tried define('WP_DEBUG', true);, define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true); and define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);. But nothing happened. It would be appreciated where I should check.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following things:

1. The SSL errors usually come in ssl_error.log. Try to find it.
2. If in httpd.conf file, it is still listening to HTTP port. So try using HTTP URL.
3. For https, try to create a test PHP file, upload in the root folder and just place following line in it:
   echo "HTTPS WITHOUT WORDPRESS WORKING FINE";

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Noman. 1. I couldn't find ssl_error.log though I try `sudo find -name ssl_error.log`. 2. There is no HTTP port in httpd.conf. 3. I can't access http as well as https.